C# List of running processes using windows services vs console app
I tried to use the version described in#37 from .NET console application as Windows service #37 with the files:

Program.cs
MyService.cs
MyServiceInstaller.cs

in order to list into a file the processes that have MainWindowsTitle completed.
For this I modified Program.cs as follows:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;


namespace MyService
{
    class Program
    {
        public const string ServiceName = "MyService";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

            if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {
                // running as console app
                Start(args);

                Console.WriteLine("Main Console: Press any key to stop...");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
 
                Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                // running as service
                using (var service = new Service())
                {
                    ServiceBase.Run(service);
                 }
            }
        }

        public static void Start(string[] args)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\MyService.txt", String.Format("======================================{0} ", Environment.NewLine));
            File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\MyService.txt", String.Format("{0} started  ", DateTime.Now));
            File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\MyService.txt", String.Format("-- Env.UserName:{0} -- Env.Version{1} --Console:{2}{3}", Environment.UserName, Environment.Version.ToString(),Environment.UserInteractive, Environment.NewLine));
            
            Thread threadProcessAnalysis = new Thread(new ThreadStart(processAnalysis));
            threadProcessAnalysis.Start();
            //threadProcessAnalysis.Join();//thrade main asteapta thread sa se termine
            //Console.WriteLine("...press a key from Start function...");
            //Console.ReadKey();
            
 
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\MyService.txt", String.Format("{0} stopped{1}", DateTime.Now, Environment.NewLine));
        }

    
        static void processAnalysis()
        {
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\MyService.txt", String.Format("Lista Procese: {0} ", Environment.NewLine));
 
            foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
            {
                if (theprocess.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("--Process: {0} --ID: {1}  --MainWindowsTitle: {2} --MWHandle: {3} {4}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id, theprocess.MainWindowTitle, theprocess.MainWindowHandle);
                    File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\MyService.txt", String.Format("--Process: {0} --ID: {1}  --MainWindowsTitle: {2} --MWHandle: {3} {4}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id, theprocess.MainWindowTitle, theprocess.MainWindowHandle, Environment.NewLine));
 
                }
            }
        }
        

    }
}

When I run from the console, the result is ok. Processes that have a title are identified and recorded in the file.
When I run as windows services, processes that have a title are not identified for record in the file.
Why the results are not ok when run as windows service?
I tested the related but all of them have same problems.

Services ar enot allowed to interact with the desktop windows, so it can't read the titles
